# 4D array into matrix

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I want to covert a 4D array into a matrix. The array looks like this

```
, , 1, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 2, 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

, , 1, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

, , 2, 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8
```

And I want to convert it to a matrix as this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    1    3
[2,]    2    4    2    4
[3,]    5    7    5    7
[4,]    6    8    6    8
```

Is there any idea how to use **loop** to do this?

Comment: Yes, I just tried to use `rbind(cbind(...))` with indices. This is just an example. I wonder if the indices are large, like the data I am trying to deal with, it is very hard to type the indices by yourself. For example , an array with dimension (192,168, 100, 100). Is there any loop that can work this out?

Comment: It is not clear how your question extends to larger dimensions. Are you sure that the array in your question has correct entries (specifically, the last two matrices)?

Comment: There are 38 folders containing multiple files(probably  more than 50, let's say 50). Each file can be converted into a matrix. I try to put the matrices of the files in the first folder to the first rows of a larger matrix  and so on. What I did was to read them into an array with dimension(192,168, 50,38) then convert it into a matrix. I'm not sure if it is a right way and I tried to put an simple example on stackexchange so you can easily understand. But it seems to be more complicated

Comment: So then again, please check whether your example data and expected output are correct. The upper left matrix in the latter is `arr[, , 1, 1]`, but the lower left matrix is `arr[, , 1, 2]` *transposed*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case,

```
matrix(aperm(arr, c(1,4,2,3)), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    3    1    3
# [2,]    2    4    2    4
# [3,]    5    7    5    7
# [4,]    6    8    6    8
```

More generally,

```
arr <- array(c(1:9, 1:9, 5:13, 5:13), c(3,3,2,2))
matrix(aperm(arr, c(1,4,2,3)), nrow = dim(arr)[1] * dim(arr)[4])
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    4    7    1    4    7
# [2,]    2    5    8    2    5    8
# [3,]    3    6    9    3    6    9
# [4,]    5    8   11    5    8   11
# [5,]    6    9   12    6    9   12
# [6,]    7   10   13    7   10   13
```

Comment: Thank you. But I still don't know how it works. what is `c(1,4,2,3)` used for? It seems not the dimension of `aper(arr,c(1,4,2,3))`

Comment: @Z.Chi, in your example `matrix(arr, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)` would already give some matrix, but the ordering is wrong. So, to make the ordering correct, `arr` has to be rearranged and that is exactly what `aperm` does. `c(1,4,2,3)` is a permutation vector for dimensions, see `?aperm`.

Comment: If I use `c(1,2,3,4)`, does it give the same result?

Comment: @Z.Chi, using `c(1,2,3,4)` gives the same as `matrix(arr, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)` since no dimensions get permuted. You should always use `c(1,4,2,3)` when having an array as in your example.

Comment: @Z.Chi, if this answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking in the top left of it.

Comment: Sure. I am still trying to understand your solution and see if it can be used in a more generalized case.

Comment: @Z.Chi, it is not trivial to understand how dimensions are permuted with `aperm`, `c(1,4,2,3)` was one of my initial guesses and that's all. Try to play with 3d arrays to see how it works. In terms of generalizing, everything works as long as your array has 4 dimensions (e.g. (192,168,100,100) as in your previous comment) and the pattern of forming a matrix is the same as in this question.